# Pyinstaller, hidden -imports, WebSocketError

Tags: python, import, pyinstaller, rpm-spec

I just run into an error that said "No module name socketio", after adding it to the hidden imports I get "No module name server" and after adding to the hidden imports socketio.server I get the new one and so on...
Is there another way to add every import my application needs?

However if I have to go this way, how can I add import:
 from .exceptions import WebSocketError, since geventwebsocket.exceptions.WebSocketError is not working.

[EDIT] Here is more informations.
My application works fine from PyCharm, after I create exe with Pyinstaller I get that error, I was doing research for adding imports that Pyinstaller did not caught and all I could find is to change .spec and to add to the hidden-imports what I need.
However I thought that adding geventwebsocket will be enough but as I said, now I get "Cannot import name WebSocketError ". So I guess my code is ok since it works perfectly before I created exe with Pyinstaller?

[EDIT] Here is my .spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['manage.py'],
pathex=['C:\\path'],
hiddenimports=['greenlet', 'hid', 'flask_bootstrap',
'flask_socketio', 'blueprints',
'hidapi', 'pywin32', 'xlrd', 'flask_wtf',
'flask_sqlalchemy', 'cython',
'flask_login', 'nexus', 'antiorm', 'colorama', 
'socket.error','config', 'cython', 
'flask_script', 'init','py', 'requests', 
'PyInstaller', 'pyDatalog', 'pytest',
 'yaml', 'terminal', 'virtualenv', 
 'geventwebsocket.server',
 'gevent.server', 'socketio', 'socketio.server', 
 'gevent.pywsgi',  
 'gevent.baseserver','geventwebsocket.handler',
 'socketio.handler', 
 'geventwebsocket.exceptions.WebSocketError',
 'socketio.transports', 
 'socketio.exceptions.WebSocketError'],
  hookspath=None,
  runtime_hooks=None)

  pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
     exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='manage.exe',
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=True )

dict_tree = Tree('app', prefix = 'app')
dict_tree += Tree('.hg', prefix = '.hg')
dict_tree += Tree('.idea', prefix = '.idea')




coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           dict_tree,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=None,
           upx=True,
           name='manage')
```

And error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\path\out00-PYZ.pyz\socketio.transports", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name WebSocketError
```

Comment: Please add code. Explain the flow of your logic, how things are connected through your code examples and try to point out where specifically you think the code is erring. This will help the community help you.

Comment: Thank you, I have edit my post, please tell if you think some other informations might help.

Comment: You need to add some code - in particular - the full process you're using to try to make your `exe` (e.g. are you just doing `pyinstaller <yourApp>.py`, or using a modified `.spec` file? Edit the question with the `.spec` file, the ***full*** traceback you see and the lines from around where the failure occurs from ***your*** code.

Comment: I was using a modified .spec file... I don't know where the failure occures in my code, my code works fine from PyCharm and python. 
I tried with hook files but I guess I'm not using it well I'm new with all of this. I found WebSocketError as a class in geventwebsocket\exception.py,

Comment: Use a minimal working example. too much superfluous detail